# How do I get the dirname of a file with Perl?

Tags: perl

In my perl script, I have the param `$FILE=/etc/sysconfig/network`

in which way (in perl) I can cut only the directory and put the directory in $DIR param

in order to get:

```
$DIR=/etc/sysconfig

(like dirname /etc/sysconfig/network in shell script)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
use File::Basename;

($name,$path,$suffix) = fileparse($fullname,@suffixlist);

$name = fileparse($fullname,@suffixlist);
$basename = basename($fullname,@suffixlist);
$dirname  = dirname($fullname);
```

Read more about [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) in perldoc.

Answer (score 41):

Watch out!  `dirname()` is deliberately dumb to emulate the `dirname` shell command.  It is not so much "give me the directory part of this file path" as "give me all but the last part of this path".  Why is that important?

```
my $dir = "/foo/bar/";   # obviously a directory
print dirname($dir);     # prints /foo
```

This is fine, just so long as you realize that `dirname` does not return the dirname.

If you want the above to return `/foo/bar/` you're better off using File::Spec.

```
use File::Spec;
my($vol,$dir,$file) = File::Spec->splitpath($path);
```

Comment: dirname() is pitfall, splitpath() is best answer; vote this as solution answer.

Comment: The directory in which `/foo/bar/` is stored, is `/foo`. So `dirname()` does the right job. The shell does exactly the same.

Comment: @ceving There's always been some confusion whether `dirname` returns the directory portion or the parent directory. [POSIX `dirname`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dirname.html) returns the directory, `dirname("/foo/bar/")` is `/foo/bar` while `dirname("/foo/bar")` is `/foo`. Shell and File::Basename's `dirname` always returns the parent. "*In effect, it is not returning the directory portion but simply the path one level up acting like "chop()" for file paths.*"

Comment: Quote from your link: "Trailing '/' characters in the path are not counted as part of the path". This means `/foo/bar/` and `/foo/bar` must return the same string, which is `/foo`. I still can not understand your confusion.

Comment: @ceving The example code in POSIX leaves a trailing newline on the path! Wow. My mistake. `dirname`'s is behavior is not obvious if you're not already familiar with C or shell. The original documentation illustrates the problem: "*The dirname() routine returns the directory portion of the input file*". Is the "directory portion" of /foo/bar/ the directory /foo/bar/ or /foo? A less ambiguous name would be `pop_path` or `parent_path` because that's really what it does. I extensively overhauled the File::Basename a number of years back. If what `dirname` does is clear, you're welcome. ;)

Answer (score 10):

Use the [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) core module:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;

my $FILE = '/etc/sysconfig/network';
my $DIR = dirname($FILE);
print $DIR, "\n";
```

This prints out:

> /etc/sysconfig