# How do i find the directory of a file in perl?

Tags: perl

I am using the directory structure which looks like :-
proto08/qa08/short/drc/cases/hello/win

I am running a perl file which is stored in "short" dir.
The perl line is parsing a file which is on "win" dir.
The file which is being parsed uses a line :-
source ../../master.txt.

I found the file name using a regex which is "../../master.txt"
and i want to parse "../../master.txt" also.

How can i do this? 
Any suggestions?

Comment: please clarify your question, it's really hard to tell what you are asking.

Comment: You may want to provide sample code or make it more clear. It sounds something like you're attempting to open a file in a subdirectory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want [`dirname`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455956/how-do-i-get-the-dirname-of-a-file-with-perl)

If you want `realpath` behaviour as well, look at the [`Cwd` core module](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html)