# perl overload file name download

Tags: perl, download, overloading, filenames

I need to be able to propose files to be downloaded but i have to read and print the file in my CGI. I tried to go for :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

push( @INC, $lib_directory );
require 'lib_utils.pl';

dl_file('/tmp/final.pdf');
```

as main page (dl.pl) and

```
sub dl_file {
    my ($file) = @_;

    if ( ! -e $file) {
        print "file does not exist";
        return 0;
    }

    my $content = read_file( $file, binmode => ':utf8' ) ;

    $file =~ m#(.*)([^/]*)$#;
    my $directory    = $1;
    my $filename    = $2;

    chdir $directory;    

    my $form = new CGI;
    print $form->header(
        -type        => 'application/octet-stream',
        -attachment    => $filename,
        -filename    => $filename,
        -Content-Disposition    => "attachment; filename=$filename",
    );

    $form->print($content);

    return 1;
}
```

for the called function. Funny thing is, this code workes just fine if i dont go for a sub and have all the code in dl.pl BUT as soon as i move the code in a sub, the downloaded file is called after the script (ie dl.pl)

How would you change it or how would you do ?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please describe the problem you are having. What are the symptoms? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line

```
$file =~ m#(.*)([^/]*)$#
```

will leave `$1` containing the whole of `$file` and `$2` empty. You need a slash in there somewhere, probably like this

```
$file =~ m#(.*)/([^/]*)$#
```

It would also make sense to make the directory optional, like so

```
$file =~ m#(?:(.*)/)?([^/]*)$#
my $directory = $1;
```

and you would have to write

```
chdir $directory if $directory
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i clearly was searching the wrong way since i wasnt suspecting the regexp at all ! thanks a lot :)

Comment: Also consider using `my ($directory, $filename) = ($file =~ m#(?:(.*)/)?([^/]*)$#);`

Comment: And look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455956/how-do-i-get-the-dirname-of-a-file-with-perl

Answer (score 0):

This is what's tripping you up:

```
$file =~ m#(.*)([^/]*)$#;
```

Looks like you're trying to split "/tmp/final.pdf" into directory and file. But you don't - that pattern splits you into:

```
    print "F:",$filename,"\n";
    print "D:",$directory,"\n";
```

this output:

```
F:
D:/tmp/final.pdf
```

This is why you have the problem - you don't have a filename, so it defaults to using the script name.

I would suggest instead you want:

```
my ( $directory, $filename ) = ( $file =~ m,(.*/)([\.\w]+)$, );
```

This gives:

```
F:final.pdf
D:/tmp/
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been said, you're suffering from the greedy matching of `.*` which will eat up the entire string:

```
$file =~ m{(.*)([^/]*)$};
```

There are three easy solutions to this

#### 1. Boundary Conditions

As has been stated, you can add a boundary condition that limits how much `.*` can match:

```
$file =~ m{(?:(.*)/)?([^/]*)$};
my $dir = $1 // '';
my $filename = $2;
```

Or this somewhat convoluted lookbehind assertion can also enforce a boundary:

```
$file =~ m{(.*)(?<![^/])([^/]*)$};
my $dir = $1;
my $filename = $2;
```

#### 2. Non-greedy matching

However, the simplest regex solution is to use non-greedy matching `.*?`:

```
$file =~ m{(.*?)([^/]*)$};
my ($dir, $filename) = ($1, $2);
```

Basically, anytime you're about to put `.*` anywhere, check your assumptions.  The majority of the time you'll actually want `.*?` instead.

#### 3. Module for parsing file paths

The bonus option is just to use a module like [`File::Spec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html) parsing file path information

```
use File::Spec;

my ($vol, $dirs, $filename) = File::Spec->splitpath( $file );
```